# WebRTC Video streaming on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying to build a Security Camera.
However, I do not want to do something like Port Forwarding to enable streaming. Nor do I want to implement a 3rd party Cloud based Streaming service like Wowza.

Under these conditions, the only way I could find was to implement WebRTC MediaStream on NodeJS

The WebRTC implementations on NodeJS are missing the MediaStream package. 
Also the MediaStream package relies heavily on built in browser code to set up and stream audio & video.

How can I do seamless audio video streaming using NodeJS?
Is it even possible? Can NodeJS (a single threaded model) do something as computationally intensive as video transcoding?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly doable.  I read a while back about a webRTC connected drone (https://tech.ipcortex.co.uk/blog/keevioeye) and there's the webRTC connected RC car (http://www.instructables.com/id/WebRTC-Creeper-Drone-Browser-Controlled-RC-Car/).  To build it from scratch you would probably need a pico motherboard with Linux Chromium installed to handle the webRTC negotiation to the server receiving the stream.

For server side MediaStream recording, transcoding and even motion detection and facial recognition I'd use the open source Kurento project which has both Java and nodeJS  libraries.